# ¿Cómo cambiar correctamente los tipos de variables para que el arreglo me guarde la información?

Tags: java, array

Quiero que mi algoritmo guarde la venta de cada día pero creo que mis variables al ser de tipo String no permite guardar información numérica

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        float ventaDia = 0;
        float totalVentas = 0;

        int[] diaVentas = new int[6];
        int lunes = diaVentas[0];
        int martes = diaVentas[1];
        int miércoles = diaVentas[2];
        int jueves = diaVentas[3];
        int viernes = diaVentas[4];
        int sábado = diaVentas[5];
        int domingo = diaVentas[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < diaVentas.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el total de ventas del día " + (i + 1) + " (en doláres): ");
            diaVentas[] = sc.nextInt();
            totalVentas += diaVentas[];
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no deberías de crear las variables de los días de la semana a menos que lo uses posteriormente, a continuación un ejemplo de como almacenar el total de ventas por día:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    float totalVentas = 0;

    int[] diaVentas = new int[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < diaVentas.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese el total de ventas del día " + (i + 1) + " (en doláres): ");
        diaVentas[i] = entrada.nextInt();
        totalVentas += diaVentas[i];
    }
    System.out.println(totalVentas);
}
```

Para este caso obtienes la suma de los 7 días de la semana, y en el caso de que quieras saber que valor te da un día específico podrías optar por llamar al array por su indice especifico, ejemplo:

```
System.out.println(diaVentas[2]);
System.out.println(diaVentas[5]);
```

En éste caso se imprime los valores de los días: `Miércoles y Sabado`

Answer (score 0):

Como funciona el `Scanner` para obtener un valor de entrada es de la siguiente forma:

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Introduce el valor: ");
int valor = entrada.nextInt();
```

Por lo tanto tienes que iterar en base a la longitud de tu array diaVentas e ingresar los valores en su posición correcta en base a su indice

```
for (int i = 0; i < diaVentas.length; i++) {
     System.out.println("Ingrese el total de ventas del día " + (i + 1) + " (en doláres): ");
          //Ingresa valor a array diaVentas.
          diaVentas[i] = entrada.nextInt();
          //Calcula totalVentas
          totalVentas += diaVentas[i];
}
```

---

Esta sería la forma adecuada:

```
   Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    float ventaDia = 0;
    float totalVentas = 0;

    int[] diaVentas = new int[6];
    int lunes = diaVentas[0];
    int martes = diaVentas[1];
    int miércoles = diaVentas[2];
    int jueves = diaVentas[3];
    int viernes = diaVentas[4];
    int sábado = diaVentas[5];
    int domingo = diaVentas[0];



for (int i = 0; i < diaVentas.length; i++) {
     System.out.println("Ingrese el total de ventas del día " + (i + 1) + " (en doláres): ");
          diaVentas[i] = entrada.nextInt();
          totalVentas += diaVentas[i];
}
```